# Displaying One Custom Post Type's Content On Single Post of Another Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, php, categories, custom-taxonomy, customization

I'm currently building a college football blog and I have 2 custom post types: `conference` and `team`.

Each `conference` post type will be a horizontal list consisting of each teams' logo and will be displayed on every `single` `team` post so long as the team is in the respective conference. It will look virtually identical to this:

[image: Horizontal List for Conference Post Type Example]

Using the [ACF plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/), I've given each `team` post type a *Conference* field from which the user can select the conference the team belongs in.

[image: Conference for Team Post Type]

Each `conference` post has the respective `HTML` already for its content.  My question is how do I proceed to make what I just described a reality using `PHP`? I'm a `PHP` newb so if the answer is obvious, please forgive me.

The website from which I got this idea is [D1ARugby.com](http://d1arugby.com). The example of what I'm trying to achieve is as follows:

[image: D1ARugby.com Team Page Example]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

## UPDATE

Here's the current template I'm using for my single-team post. It works for conferences whose name is just a single word and not multiple words.

```
<?php
    // get team posts
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $team_args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 1,
        'post_type'        => 'team',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true,
        'paged'            => $paged
    );
    $conf_args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 1,
        'post_type'        => 'conference',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true,
        'paged'            => $paged
    );

    $teams = get_posts($team_args);
    $conferences = get_posts($conf_args);

    foreach($teams as $team) : setup_postdata($team);
?>

    <section id="conference" class="row">

        <?php foreach($conferences as $conf) : setup_postdata($conf); ?>
        <div class="conf-header">
            <?php
                $conference_name = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'conference', true );
                $conference = get_page_by_title( $conference_name, OBJECT, 'conference' );
            ?>
            <h1 class="conference-title"><?php echo $conference_name; ?></h1>
            <?php 
                if ($conference) {
                    echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $conference->post_content );
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </section>
```

I can figure out why it will display for conferences named "California" and "West" but it won't display for conferences named "Big Ten" or "Red River." Any ideas as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You'll need to jump into the [post types single template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display) file and write yourself a [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) that will pull post(s) and then you can [Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) through them to display the content or whatever you need.

Comment: Any answer for this will need to mention the template hierarchy, what post meta is, and how ACF uses it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer! It turns out that in ACF, if you're using radio buttons and have key set for each value, the keys **CAN** in fact contain spaces! By matching the keys to the values (case-insensitive) I was able to get the conferences to display on the single-team posts.

Answer (score 1):

The code you need will vary slightly depending on whether the Conference field is storing a text string (like "Big Ten") vs. the ID of the Conference post. I'll include both:

**Text String Example**

```
// place this code inside the loop of your single-team template
$conference_name = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'conference', true );
$conference = get_page_by_title( $conference_name, OBJECT, 'conference' );

if ($conference) {
    echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $conference->post_content );
}
```

**ID Example**

```
// place this code inside the loop of your single-team template
$conference_id = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'conference', true );
$conference = get_post( $conference_id );

if ($conference) {
    echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $conference->post_content );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Not sure if this will help but I've gone ahead and created custom taxonomies named `Conferences` grouping the teams in their designated conferences along with the `conference` post types as well.  Is using taxonomies an easier way of achieving what I'm going for?

Using your method, I was able to get all the conference logos to load but it was **every** conference loading at once. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Huh, that's strange. It should only show the content from the Conference that you've associated with the current team. Can you edit your question to include the code from your Single Team template?

Using a taxonomy to group the teams is certainly one way to go, but I think it probably adds a layer of complexity that you don't need. It sounds like you're really close to getting it sorted out, but for some reason it's selecting multiple conferences instead of one.

Comment: I've updated my question to include the template I'm currently using. Got it to work for conferences but only if it's a single word name and not a multiple word name.

Comment: I've updated my question and my example. Any ideas would be much appreciated.